# Change cursor on a Run inside UWP TextBlock

Tags: uwp

I have a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock` that contains multiple `Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Run` elements in its `TextBlock.Inlines` collection. I need to change the mouse cursor when it is pointing to one of these inlines (let's say `tb.Inlines[1]`).

Is there a way to change the cursor just for a **specific `Inline`**? I change it for the **whole** `TextBlock` by subscribing to PointerEntered and PointerExited events and changing the mouse cursor for the app. But these events are defined on the `UIElement`, and an individual Inline is not a `UIElement`.

As additional info. This is part of a Xamarin Forms app, so I have little control over how the TextBlock and its Inlines are created (unless I create custom renderers, which is a whole other can of worms). All I can do is access already-created TextBlock and the Inlines inside it; modify some properties on them, subscribe to events on them, etc.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to break the single `TextBlock` into several `TextBlock` elements and handle the events for them seperately.

Comment: Can't break the TextBlock, because I am not creating it. Xamarin Forms creates all the platform-specific elements and on UWP it happens to be a TextBlock.

Comment: I think mm8 means put your text into several `TextBlock` elements. You don't need to custom the `TextBlock` elements. Just add more `TextBlock` elements and handle the events like what you did now.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Instead of using a single `TextBlock` that contains several inlines, you should use several `TextBlock` elements.

Comment: Separate TextBlocks will not wrap correctly. Consider the case with 3 inlines. The middle inline is for bold text. The complete text takes up two lines. The bold part starts somewhere in the middle of first line and ends somewhere in the middle of second line.
There is no way to arrange this into 3 separate TextBlocks. I could arrange them into 4 TextBlocks (regular, bold, bold, regular), but then I would need to know where to put the line break, which may vary from system to system and from execution to execution.

Comment: If you don't want to use several `TextBlock`, you might need to detect the position of your cursor in the PointerMove event. It is not sure if this is could be done.